# GLSurfaceView renders distorted image on Asus Transformer

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing a photo gallary widget on android that should implement some features like a flip between photos and curl effect which do impress that photo sheet curls on touch and shows underlaying sheet with some comments for photo.
I've implemented that with ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter which create instance of Fragment that contains GLSurfaceView with renderer that produces curl effect with opengl-es 2.0.

I've tested this solution on Kindle Fire HD 7` and many types of Sumsung devices from  Ace (2.3.3) to Galaxy Tab 10' - works fine. But on Asus Transformer tf700t I've got awful distorted image.

[Kindle Fire HD Screenshoot](http://clip2net.com/s/5bp9tB)

[Distorted image on Asus Transformer](http://clip2net.com/s/5bp9v2)

Does anybody face with similar problem? Is there some peculiarity in initialisation GLES2.0 context for Tegra 3 GPU unlike mali400 or PowerVR?

My GLSurfaceView constructor code:

```
    /// Конструктор для создания поверхности в runtime с уже загруженой текстурой
public MainGLSurfaceView(Context context, Bitmap bm) {
    super(context);

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    /// следующие три строчки - для того чтобы из под поверхности было видно другие view
    setZOrderOnTop(true);
    //setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);


    /// было хорошо на Kindle но плохо на Asus transformer и телефонах
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

    /// попытка сделать хорошо везде
    //setEGLConfigChooser(true);

    //getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_4444);

    //Bitmap bmTemp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.temp_bitmap);
    mRenderer = new MainGLRenderer(context,bm,bm, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE,-20f);
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}
```

Renderer OnSurfaceCreated:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    /// смешивание

    GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE);

    /// z-буффер
    GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    /// не отрисовывать изнанку полигонов
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);

    //GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    /// функция z-буффера
    GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_LEQUAL );

    /// тоже что-то для z-буффера
    GLES20.glDepthMask( true );

    /// сделать цвет фона фрейма - по нулям для прозрачности
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Texture from bitmap constructor:

```
public Texture(Bitmap bm) {
        //создаем пустой массив из одного элемента
        //в этот массив OpenGL ES запишет свободный номер текстуры, 
        // который называют именем текстуры
        int []names = new int[1];
        // получаем свободное имя текстуры, которое будет записано в names[0]
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, names, 0);
        //запомним имя текстуры в локальном поле класса
        name = names[0];
        //теперь мы можем обращаться к текстуре по ее имени name
        //устанавливаем режим выравнивания по байту
        GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        //делаем текстуру с именем name текущей
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, name);
        //устанавливаем фильтры текстуры
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                //GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                //GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);


        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                //GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                //GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        //переписать Bitmap в память видеокарты
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bm, 0);

        // удалить Bitmap из памяти, т.к. картинка уже переписана в видеопамять
        bm.recycle();
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

        GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Sorry about long post. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_LEQUAL ) to GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_ALWAYS );

Comment: You need to clear the depth buffer every frame using `glClearDepthf(1.0f); glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` because Transformer sometimes doesn't initialize rendering buffers to zero (and the standard does not require so).